# Aplicação com Drag and Drop e outros efeitos

Tags: c#, modelagem, drag-n-drop

Estou me preparando para fazer o meu TCC e o resultado dele será um aplicativo. Neste aplicativo eu vou modelar objetos. Para modelar esse objetos o aplicativo irá fornecer algumas formas. Essas formas deverão ser arrastadas até uma área do aplicativo. Será necessário interligar essas partes para para identificar uma ordem ou algo do gênero.

Para fornecer uma noção melhor, o [Dia Diagram](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dia-installer/) e o brModelo [brModelo](http://www.sis4.com/brmodelo/download.aspx) são semelhantes ao que desejo fazer em relação a modelagem.

Gostaria de saber se alguém pode me ajudar com sugestões ou direcionamentos para que eu consiga fazer algo parecido pois não possuo experiência com este tipo de trabalho.

Costumo usar `C#` mas aceito sugestões de outras linguagens para desenvolver esta aplicação.

Comment: [Acho que isso pode te ajudar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981840/how-to-draw-and-move-shapes-using-mouse-in-c-sharp).

Comment: Pretende desenvolver para qual plataforma? Desktop, web, mobile?

Comment: Pretendo desenvolver Desktop, porém já andei pensando em talvez fazer web caso o esforço seja significativamente menor. A ideia de fazer desktop é para que o usuário possa utilizar sem conexão e também para que eu não tenha custos com servidor para manter o aplicativo. A ideia é que após a conclusão do app ele seja disponibilizado free e open.